Underground City Temperature. Is it possible for an underground city/settlement to be cold?
I am trying to envision an underground city and I'm uncertain of wether or not the general climate would be cold or hot.
In one hand, the lack of sunlight and overall isolation from surface weather would lead me to think that the city or zone in general would be cold. However, the closest one gets to the core of the earth the hotter.
Also, I am unsure of how would air flow and pressure affect the environmental temperature.
I have envisioned the city as generally cold and I would want it to stay that way, but I also want it to be realistic in a way.

How deep underground and how large is the city? In general, the biggest problem for an underground structure where people live is ventilation. And then the second biggest problem is cooling, because dirt and rock are thermal insulators and a city is supposed to do something; cities are not normally places where people just sit idle.

Is this on Earth or an Earth-like world?  If not Earth then how Earth-like is it?

@AlexP is right, rock is a great insulator. While geological factors contribute to deep mines being hot, the bigger problem is the heat generated by human activity. There's simply nowhere for the heat to go quickly. Atmosphere moves heat much faster than the ground. So if you're talking about a large city, there'd be a lot of heat to pump away to keep the city cool. Not being a geologist, I don't know if location would matter enough (e.g., arctic or oceanic vs. desert) other than for the atmospheric pumping requirement.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@KerrAvon2055 yes, it's in an earth-like world. Pretty much earth.

@AlexP and JBH You both are totally right. Naturally human beings and their activities produce a lot of heat. I suppose my focus should now be how could there possibly be ventilation or any medium that absorbs and moves heat around.

Cave temperature averages the air temperature of the surface environment.
If you want colder caves, put the caves in a colder polar environment. For warmer caves, warmer equatorial environments.
Of course, core heating kicks in as you get deeper. One source I looked at said about 25C/km. The effect may be more exaggerated: the cave of crystals, in Mexico, when not flooded, was >50C.

What if the cave is in a mountain underwater ? would this have an effect on the temperature ?
